# Allocatable array is already allocated when interfacing Fortran with R

Tags: r, fortran, allocation, interfacing

I am  working on interfacing some modern Fortran code with R and get the following error:

`forrtl: severe (151): allocatable array is already allocated`

Even though the error message is the same, I don't think the origin of this issue is not directly related with this entry
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157631/forrtl-severe-151-allocatable-array-is-already-allocated)

---

The problem/background:

I have compiled my Fortran code myself as shared object, using `ifort` and the relevant flags

I can call the shared object using `.Fortran` once in R. Then I have to do
    `dyn.unload("HX.so")`
in order to then reload it  (`dyn.load("HX.so"`) and rerun it.

Just running and rerunning an R script that finishes the R session in between works fine.

During single runs and after loading and unloading in R, the content that is passed back to me in my R session or printed during running the R script is the expected output.

Here is what else is shown after the error message:

```
forrtl: severe (151): allocatable array is already allocated
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
libifcoremt.so.5   00007FF6276E7432  for_alloc_allocat     Unknown  Unknown
HX.so              00007FF628464F3F  init_                 Unknown  Unknown
HX.so              00007FF62845F2D1  hx_                   Unknown  Unknown
libR.so            00007FF637316E76  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libR.so            00007FF63734EC8B  Rf_eval               Unknown  Unknown
libR.so            00007FF63735213E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libR.so            00007FF63734EA93  Rf_eval               Unknown  Unknown
libR.so            00007FF637351060  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libR.so            00007FF63734EA93  Rf_eval               Unknown  Unknown
libR.so            00007FF6373500C7  Rf_applyClosure       Unknown  Unknown
libR.so            00007FF63734E86F  Rf_eval               Unknown  Unknown
libR.so            00007FF63735213E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libR.so            00007FF63734EA93  Rf_eval               Unknown  Unknown
libR.so            00007FF637376102  Rf_ReplIteration      Unknown  Unknown
libR.so            00007FF637376451  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libR.so            00007FF63737650F  run_Rmainloop         Unknown  Unknown
R                  000000000040080B  main                  Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.17.so       00007FF633E77C05  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
R                  000000000040083B  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

---

What I have tried so far:

As the error message suggests, I have identified all `ALLOCATED` `ALLOCATABLES` and looked whether they are all `DEALLOCATED` as well. I did find a few that were not, but that has not solved the issue.

I checked that the Fortran code is running until the end using a simple `WRITE (*,*) 'END'` statement before `END SUBROUTINE`.

---

The aim is to be able to call the Fortran code many times in R, to do sensitivity analysis- so, always having to unload and load it would slow things down substantially.

If you think I need to provide more information, let me know.

---

edit:
compiling with -g -traceback does not catch anything at run or compile time.

compiling with -g -traceback -check  catches the following error at runtime:

```
forrtl: severe (151): allocatable array is already allocated
Image              PC                Routine            Line            Source
libifcoremt.so.5   00007F52C1432432  for_alloc_allocat     Unknown  Unknown
HX.so              00007F52C21D890F  init_                      27  INIT.f90
HX.so              00007F52C21B685B  hx_                       278 HX.f90
libR.so            00007F52D1095E76  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libR.so            00007F52D10CDC8B  Rf_eval               Unknown  Unknown
..see above.
```

line 278 in the "main" subroutine (HX) calls subroutine INIT, which then in line 27 shows an `ALLOCATABLE`. Doing grep I have not found it being allocated anywhere else. NOTE: but it also was not deallocated anywhere..

all flags used:

```
F90 = ifort
FFLAGS = -O3 -fpic -r8 -g -check -traceback  # double-precision now run in Fortran , -fpic for creating shared object file
LDFLAGS = -lnetcdff -lnetcdf -shared   #-shared, for creating a shared object file
```

My R-code:

```
dyn.load("HX.so")

 years<-c(2007,2008,2009)
 n_years<-as.integer(length(years))
 y<-array(0,dim=c(14,6,n_years))
 run_model <- function(pa=params) {
 out<-.Fortran('HX',pa,n_years,array(as.numeric(0),dim=c(14,6,n_years)))
 return(out)
 }
out<-run_model(c(30,2))
out
```

---

NOTE- solution:
It was actually a `DEALLOCATE` issue.. Not all allocated arrays had been deallocated by the end of the run..and I simply had not found them all ( even though that was one of therouble shooting attempts I had made in advance of posting this..)
Is my guess correct that maybe the compiler didn't pick up on the issue because unlike in [the previous post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157631/forrtl-severe-151-allocatable-array-is-already-allocated), the (de-)allocation was not technically in a loop ( until I turned the Fortran executable into a shared object)? 
I would find this surprising, but the only info I found is that deallocation is just ["good programming practice"](http://www.pcc.qub.ac.uk/tec/courses/f90/stu-notes/F90_notesMIF_11.html) ?

Comment: Welcome. Where is your code? See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: How can you have `PROGRAM` and `END PROGRAM` in an `.so` library? There is something fishy here. Please show the actual code.

Comment: *"using `ifort` and the relevant flags"* Please always try to show relevant information if you have it. That includes the flags. Do not say "relevant flags". Show the actual `ifort ...` command instead. Compile your programs with `-g -traceback` to get better info including line numbers.

Comment: sorry about that. The PROGRAM is of course SUBROUTINE, which it also is in my code.  Am now showing all relevant flags. The code is huge.. I will try to break it down into the important bits. But I might not know what the important bits are and omit them accidentally ):

Comment: The `251 ELSE` is obviously useless. You must show at least the complete subroutine. But notice the error caught by `-check` is a different one anyway.

Comment: sorry i thought that that error message simply shows that it has something to do with the below, where the conditions are now adequate and the code runs. Yes. I noticed that and have for now commented out the writing of that file. That way I am back to the allocatable array error message from before. Will edit above